# How can I find a specific string and replace based on character?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to find a specific character, for example '?' and then remove all text behind the char until I hit a whitespace.

So that:

```
var string = '?What is going on here?';
Then the new string would be: 'is going on here';
```

I have been using this:

```
var mod_content = content.substring(content.indexOf(' ') + 1);
```

But this is not valid anymore, since the specific string also can be in the middle of a string also.

I haven't really tried anything but this. I have no idea at all how to do it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, hence the edit.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Of course not. Sorry. I'm just using it together with jQuery. I were just to fast adding jQuery.

Comment: What do you expect/hope to happen if there is no question mark, no space, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
string = string.replace(/\?\S*\s+/g, '');
```

***Update:***
If want to remove the last `?` too, then use

```
string = string.replace(/\?\S*\s*/g, '');
```

Comment: This works perfect, thanks a lot :) I will accept your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I've given wrong information. I wan't the '?' in the end of a string to also be removed. Is this possible?

Comment: @Kolind When you removed the `\s`, the first space will be left.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstBit = str.split("?");
var bityouWant = firstBit.substring(firstBit.indexOf(' ') + 1);
```